# Python Getdist library : issue with shift between lines contours and filled contour

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, fill

I am faced now to a new problem using GetDist library available on [home page of GetDist](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Examples are given in this [getdist plot gallery](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plot_gallery.html).

This is a tool to plot joint distribution for a set of covariance matrices.

Everything works fine except one detail that disturbs me : If I zoom very deeply, I notice a slight shift between the contours filled and the lines contours. I illustrate this by the following zoomed figure (smallest contours refers to 1 sigma uncertainty and the largest 2 sigma) representing the ellipse of 2 covariance matrices.

[image: illustration of not wanted space between filled area and lines contours]

In this figure, I zoom very deeply on a subplot. Classically, if I unzoom the figure, I get this kind of image :

[image: classical triplot]

The relevant section that generates the triplot is :

```
# Call triplot
g.triangle_plot([matrix1, matrix2],
                names,
                filled = True,
                legend_labels = [],
                contour_colors = ['darkblue','red'],
                line_args = [{'lw':2, 'color':'darkblue'},
                {'lw':2, 'color':'red'}],
                )
```

I don't understand why filled area (red and darkblue) exceeds slightly the lines of the corresponding contours.

Maybe it is related to my conputation of limits of ellipse along `x-coordinates` and `y-coordinates` in order to fully fill the subplot and the rounding errors. I tried to modify these paramters without success.

Comment: Please don't put answers in questions here - you have been here long enough to know this. Add a self-answer if you wish to summarise someone else's answer, or build an answer based on another one (this re-use is OK, it just needs to be posted as an answer).

Comment: Can you explain why you have removed a swathe of code from your question? Might that not be useful for visitors who are reading this question in the future? Was that not useful context that enabled Lenny to answer you?

Comment: @halfer The solution was just an option related to the settings of figure, not all the whole code which is by the way badly implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked in the code, but what I can see from the image is, that the border is half inset and half outset. I assume that the border has a transparency like the shape's fill color and thus it has the effect of a shifted dark border while this is just the part where the transparent border and the transparent background overlay.

[image]

The following example shows two circles, with a backgroundcolor rgba(0,0,0,0.5). The border on circle A has no opacity: rgb(0,0,0,1) while on circle B the border color matches the fill color (so 50% opacity: rgba(0,0,0,0.5).

Comment: Thanks, I have found the keyword to set to 1.0. I will award the bounty to you as soon as possible. Regards